# Django admin. TabularInline. How to show ForeignKey related model in TabulatInline view

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-admin

I trying to show in my django-admin, related model of related model.
Right now my models and admin.py looks like:

```
class CharacterChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CharacterModel
    fields = ['nickname', 'gender', 'image']
    extra = 1


class UserModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': [
                'username', 'email', 
                ...
            ]
        })
    ]
    inlines = [CharacterChoiceInline]

admin.site.register(User, UserModelAdmin)
```

My `CharacterModel` is related with another model `RaceModel`.

```
class RaceModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Race", max_length=254)
    character = models.ForeignKey("CharacterModel",
        null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+')


class CharacterModel(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField("Character nickname", max_length=254)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER, max_length=10, default='male')
    image = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

In Admin it looks like so:

[image]

How can I add this additional `RaceModel` field as part of `CharacterChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):` to be able to choice "race" for each character trough user admin view?

Answer (score 1):

You may find it helpful to make an admin page for a single CharacterModel first, to get things working, then go back to working on the UserModel admin screen.

What you are trying to do is straightforward. Just add a ForeignKey field to CharacterModel called `race`. It'll show up in your form as a drop-down select with the race options. I'd suggest adding an explicit `id` field to your RaceModel; you don't want to link the fields by name. You want a primary key that won't change if you edit the text.

Comment: `character` can have only one `race` but `race` can have one or more `characters`, thats why I have defined it this way

Comment: Yes, if you add a ForeignKey field to CharacterModel called race, there can be many characters for each race.

Comment: And I'll be able to query trough `race` model all related characters? lets say: race humans have 120 character objects

Comment: Yes, you could iterate through the reverse relationship, charactermodel_set, on race objects.